# copy data from one server to another using query in import/export wizard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-migration

I have one table a in one db server..and table b in another server.

I would like to update the table b using values in table a.

How do I specify the server name in query ?

```
UPDATE SELECT * from [db1].[dbo].StgMGBPData
   SET ASO_Ind = [db2].[dbo].Customer_Names.ASO_Ind,
       Company = [db2].[dbo].Customer_Names.Company,
       Rpt_Cust_ID = [db2].[dbo].Customer_Names.Rpt_Cust_ID
  FROM [db2].[dbo].Customer_Names
  JOIN [db1].[dbo].StgMGBPData ON [db2].[dbo].Customer_Names.Src_Cust_ID = [db1].[dbo].StgMGBPData.CustomerID
```

Comment: A [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) instance would make this very easy

Comment: we cant use linked server bcoz of some security constraint

Comment: [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) would work for the security conscious, because it wouldn't create an object.  I understand, though I don't see how capturing data that will require an account on the other system is really any different.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But OpenQuery..openrowset..nothing is allowed :(. can't we specify the name of server name ?

Comment: For a remote database instance?  Only after having setup a Linked Server instance.

Comment: I mean...in the above query...can we specify the server name ?

Comment: My previous comment addresses exactly that

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server, and you didn't say you want this done automatically.  Can you use the "Import and Export Data" tool in Management Studio?  It allows you to cross-load data from one db to another quite easily.

Comment: I have used the Import/Export wizard in Management studio 2008. But In that I have specified source/destination server/database. But how do I specify the db server name in the above query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try linked server because without linked server you can't use server name in query.

You can use `sp_addlinkedserver`. See an example here:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
   @server = 'SERVER',-- your servername
   @provider = 'SQLOLEDB',
   @srvproduct = '',
   @datasrc = 'SERVER', -- your servername
   @catalog = 'NHS_032808' 
   -- your database name which you want to connect
```

Like that exec the procedure with like that parameter after
you can fire the query in connected database like below.

```
select * from SERVER.NHS_032808.dbo.tbl_resident_mst
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions i will take care of this points next time

Answer (score 0):

If lack of permissions prevents you from using  Linked Server yet you are able to connect to both servers from a client and have the necessary select-permissions on the table in server A and the necessary update/insert permissions on the table in server B, then you could use Micorosoft JET in your client to bridge the servers. Data from server A is pulled out to the client where it is then pushed to server B. This falls under the general category of "heterogeneous joins", which was one of the major strengths of JET in an enterprise (multi-server) scenario. This bridging requires more bandwidth than a Linked Server approach does, but it will get the job done.   You would create links in JET to the tables in each server and would thereafter be able to refer to both within the same query.